# How to alternatively access accessors as array indices?

Tags: ruby, method-missing

I have a class `Foo` which has several methods like `button_0_0`, `button_0_1`, `button_0_2`, `button_1_0`, etc.

I would like to be able to access these alternatively via the following syntax:

```
foo.button[0][1]
foo.button[1][2]
# etc.
```

I know I could just create a `@button` instance variable and iterate through all the `button_*` accessors and add them that way, but that seems a bit kludgy and doesn't really follow the "ruby way" of doing things.

I was wondering if there was a more succinct, Rubyish solution to this problem (maybe by using `method_missing`?)—Does anyone know a better way of doing this?

(I've figured this out partway, but I get stuck at the square brackets because `[]` calls a new method on the missing method...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Foo
  def button
    Button.new(self)
  end
  def button_0_1
    "zero-one"
  end
  def button_0_2
    "zero-two"
  end

  private
  class Button
    def initialize(parent)
      @parent           = parent
      @first_dimension  = nil
    end
    def [](index)
      if @first_dimension.nil?
        @first_dimension = index
        self
      else
        @parent.send("button_#{@first_dimension}_#{index}")
      end
    end
  end
end
puts Foo.new.button[0][1]
puts Foo.new.button[0][2]
```

Comment: Instead of using `method_missing` in class Foo, can't you just do

    def button
      return Button.new(self)
    end
?

Comment: yes, i dont need method_missing. i updated the code with your suggestion. thanks.